# How to call a remote navigation menu in html?

Tags: html, menu, navigation

everytime I make a new tab in my nav menu, I need to edit all my html files.
How do I make a remote file with all the nav items, that I then call to show up?

Comment: If I understand correctly, are you looking for XMLHttpRequest or Fetch?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Simple: make your navigation into a separate HTML file and use an iframe to call it.

Another way is to make it one whole HTML file and use the following:

```js
var d = {
  e: function(id){
    return(document.getElementById(id) || "err:404");
  },
  v: function(id){
    return(document.getElementById(id).value || "err:404");
  }
};
var System = {
    tabs: {
        init: function(){
            try{
                var tabs = d.e("tabs").querySelectorAll("tab");
                for(var i = 0; i < tabs.length; i++){
                    var e = tabs[i];
                    e.onclick = function(){
                        System.tabs.activate(this);
                    };
                }
                System.tabs.activate(tabs[0]);
            }catch(err){
                alert(err.stack);
            }
        },
        activate: function(name){
            try{
                var tabs = d.e("tabs").querySelectorAll("tab");
                for(var i = 0; i < tabs.length; i++){
                    tabs[i].setAttribute("active","false");
                }
                name.setAttribute("active","true");
                var contents = d.e("content").querySelectorAll("pane");
                for(var i = 0; i < contents.length; i++){
                    contents[i].style.display = "none";
                }
                contents[Array.from(tabs).indexOf(name)].style.display = "block";
            }catch(err){
                alert(err.stack);
            }
        }
    }
};
window.onload = function(){
  System.tabs.init();
};
```

```css
tab{
  display: inline-block;
  background: #000000;
  color: #888888;
  height: 20px;
  border-right: 1px solid #444444;
  border-left: 1px solid #444444;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #222222;
}
tab[active="false"]:hover{
  background: #000000;
  color: #ffffff;
}
tab[active="true"]{
  background: #080808;
  color: #ffffff;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #000000;
}
tab[active="true"]:hover{
  background: #181818;
  color: #ffffff;
}
```

```html
<div id="tabs">
    <tab>Tab name</tab><tab>Another tab name</tab>
</div>
<div id="content">
    <pane>
        <p>Hi there! Welcome to some tab program I made! Please click the tab labeled <code>Another tab name</code> to test out the feature.</p>
    </pane>
    <pane>
        <p>The best part is: no need for element IDs or JQuery or any of that difficult stuff! Feel free to click as many times as you want to see how perfect the tabs work.</p>
    </pane>
</div>
```

I realized that the first option might not work with the current knowledge I know. It is still possible though. Meanwhile the second is obviously gonna work very good even though all I know is that it can work in Chrome, but I can't test it in other browsers because this is a school Chromebook that I am on and my dad is refusing to repair mine and my brother's shared PC.